# Notice: Undefined index: is_in_stock in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/VariationHandler

Tags: configurable-product, products

When attempting to create Configurable products, we are receiving the error below. I've disabled any 3rd party modules I thought could be causing the issue, we were using both Bss_CustomProductAttributeExport and Elgentos_LargeConfigProducts, but the error persists with both of them disabled. Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Notice: Undefined index: is_in_stock in /home/complete/bookletstomorrow.com/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/VariationHandler.php on line 206

We are running Magento 2.3.0 on PHP7.1.32

Comment: disable third party module remove in database `setup_module` table ???

Comment: @MohitPatel are there any adverse effects to removing the associated lines from that table? After some more tinkering, it seems the problem may have something to do with creating a new product that uses a previously deleted products SKU or name

Comment: No, But you remove only third party disable module Bss Custom Product Attribute Export and Elgentos_LargeConfig Products. And otherwise first backup your database